# IntelliJ "File..." action is showing directories when I want it to just show files

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

[image]

I could swear that this wasn't the behavior on an older version. Is there any way to make it so the `File...` action only displays actual files, and not directories? It's incredibly frustrating to have to always be suggested a directory first instead of a file, since (in my opinion) jumping to a directory is totally useless - all it does is scroll you in the folder/projects view to that directory..

Edit: IntelliJ version is: `IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2, Build #IU-173.4127.27`.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: Whoops, probably should've mentioned that. IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2, Build #IU-173.4127.27.

Comment: When using 2017.2.3 I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe. Instead, the behaviour is as I expected it to be i.e. in the `Find Files` action, files are displayed unless you add a forward slash suffix to your input in which case folders are found. So perhaps something has regressed between 2017.2.3 and 2017.3.2. Might be worth looking for / raising an issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I didn't see it mentioned in another issue so I [opened one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184492)

Comment: Note: if it's classes you are looking for you can use the class browser instead of the file browser to side step this issue i.e. use `Navigate > Class` instead of `Navigate > File` or `CTRL+SHIFT+T` instead of `CTRL+SHIFT+R`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that! That'll do the job for now. As an aside, according to the IntelliJ team the behavior I've described here is apparently now the intended behavior. I personally don't agree with the change but at least it resolves this as question as "not-a-bug"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in comments on the Youtrack issue I opened, this is now intended behavior due to the directory being a better match than the file (case sensitivity).

This is resolved for me with these possible solutions:

1. Use `Navigate > Class` instead, as suggested by glytching. Works well for most purposes since it handles many languages just fine.
2. Type a `.` to ignore directories. This, for me, is easier to incorporate into muscle memory than hitting Shift to capitalize or hitting Up/Down to scroll around the list of suggestions.